# Airflow task for uploading file to S3 Bucket using boto3 cause Python to Crash and Task Fails

Tags: python, amazon-s3, airflow, boto3

I'm having severe problems when uploading files in a task on airflow to upload files to an S3 Bucket on AWS. This should be simple, as I seen in some tutorials, but it's crashing on my machine. I have the following DAG definition file:

```
upload_s3.py
```

Implemented as follows in my days folder:

```
import os
import boto3
import pandas as pd

from io import StringIO

from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

from airflow import DAG

from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator


FILES_DIR  = os.environ['AIRFLOW_FILES_DIR']

BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['AIRFLOW_S3_BUCKETNAME']

BUCKET_REGION = os.environ['AIRFLOW_S3_BUCKETREGION']

KEY_ID = os.environ['AIRFLOW_S3_KEYID']

ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AIRFLOW_S3_ACCESSKEY']


def uplpad_s3():
    path_file = os.path.join(FILES_DIR, 'test.csv')
    df = pd.read_csv(path_file)
    csv_buffer = StringIO()
    df.to_csv(csv_buffer)

    s3 = boto3.client(service_name='s3',
                      region_name=BUCKET_REGION,
                      aws_access_key_id=KEY_ID,
                      aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_KEY)

    s3.put_object(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue(),
                  Bucket=BUCKET_NAME,
                  Key='test.csv')


default_args = {
        'owner': 'prea.ninja',
        'start_date': datetime(2021, 3, 17),
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'retries': 0,
        }

dag = DAG(
        'TESTE_DAG',
        default_args=default_args,
        description='Test Upload for S3 BUCKET',
        schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
)

upload_task = PythonOperator(
            task_id='UPLOAD_S3',
            python_callable=uplpad_s3,
            dag=dag
)
```

But when I run the DAG, it always crashes Python and gives me no extra information on the Airflow logs:

[Airflow Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfvtP.png)

[Airflow Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CIL1.png)

[Python Crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErgYx.png)

The weird thing is that, if i run the boto3 code in an isolated python script, I can successfully upload the files and check them on the S3 interface.  But when the connection is made inside a task, I have this issue.

---

For anyone how may have this issue, it worked fine after doing

```
export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES
```

and then restarted the webserver and scheduler o my macbook. For further information visit the link proposed by @Jacob on the comments:

https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/10435

Comment: Not solve your question, but if you install the library s3fs you can do directly df.to_csv(s3://bucket/key). Also, if you don't want to do that, I would recommend you to use S3Hook from airflow, that handles boto3 for you

Comment: I've also tried to use S3Hook, create a connection on the UI using the credential, but it get the same error. I will try s3fs to see if works.

Comment: Try changing your airflow version as suggested [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/10435)

Comment: Thanks so much @JacobCelestine, it worked fine after I used export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES